# Finish all instances of an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, multiple-instances

Let's say I have 3 activities, **A**, **B**, and **C**.

**A** is my home activity. From **A**, I can launch **B**, and from **B**, I can launch **C**. What I want to achieve is when pressing Back to always return to the home activity **A**. So, in all cases I want my activity stack to be either **A -> B**, or **A -> C**, nothing in between.

- Case 1 ✔

In activity **B**, I have one network listener that when called, will launch the same activity with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag. So **A -> B1 -> B2** works great since **B1** is destroyed and my stack is now **A -> B2**.

- Case 2 ✔

I have one more network listener that when called, will launch activity **C**. Before launching activity **C**, I call `finish()` to destroy activity **B**. So, similarly **A -> B -> C**, results to **A -> C**, because I'm calling `finish()` before launching the new intent.

- Case 3: The issue

The two network listeners are being called at the same time. **B1** is starting **B2** and just after that, **B1** is starting **C**. So I am having the following situation: **A -> B1 -> B2 -> C**. Although I am calling `finish()` before launching **C**, it will of course destroy **B1**, because that's the activity that started the **C** intent, however (apparently) **B2** won't be destroyed. **B2** is a new instance which was launched just before **C**, so I am stuck with the following activity stack: **A -> B2 -> C**, while what I am trying to achieve is **A -> C**. (since **C** was the last activity that was launched, I want to destroy all instances of **B**)

Is there a way, before starting activity **C**, to finish all instances of activity **B**? So, if **B1** starts **B2** and just after that, **B1** starts **C**, I want both **B1** and **B2** to be destroyed.

All intents are being launched with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the tag `launchMode="singleTask"` on your `Activity` declaration in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, so you'll only have one instance of it, and when you finish it, there'll be no other instances.

Another way to achieve that is to use the [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or an [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), and once you want to kill those Activities, you just have to fire a Bradcast/Event and call `finish()` accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. B1 is launching B2, then B1 is launching C. And although B1 is destroyed, B2 stays in the activity stack. What I want to achieve is if I call finish() in B1, to destroy all instances of the activity, not just B1.

Comment: B1 and B2 are instances of the same Activity?

Comment: Yes, B1 launches simultaneously B2 and C. Before starting C, I am calling finish() to destroy B, however that destroys B1, but not B2.

Comment: Do you care wether or not other Activities will be destroyed? You could use the CLEAR_TASK flag on your Intent.

Comment: Since A is the home screen, I want to keep it in stack. I want to achieve an "A -> C" stack

Comment: I believe you could try some sort of LocalBroadcast or even EventBus to notify the Activities to call "finish()" themselves.

Comment: Yes, it seems the only way. I was hoping for a cleaner solution but I guess there isn't one. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I actually changed the implementation and didn't test the LocalBroadcast neither the EventBus. Thanks for the help, though!